# Access google storage client using dictionary

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a service account in a form of dictionary. Below is the service account

```
service_account = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "private_key_id": "private_key_id",
  "private_key":  "PRIVATE KEY",
  "client_email": "email",
  "client_id": "111111",
  "auth_uri": "https://auth.com",
  "token_uri": "https://token.com",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://certs.com",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.cert.com"
}
```

The above details are simulated. I want to access the google storage using the above dictionary but not using ".json" file. Below is the code that I am trying

```py
    from google.cloud import storage
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    file_data = json.loads(blob.download_as_string())
```

Getting the below error

```
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_account)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 106, in from_service_account_json
    with io.open(json_credentials_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_fi:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can be done with the
[from_service_account_info()](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operations_client.html#google.api_core.operations_v1.AbstractOperationsClient.from_service_account_info) method instead of `from_service_account_json`.